# Logging on console and in different files in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I need help with logging in python 2.7.

My directory structure is 
[image]

I have 3 different functions in file called hydra:
lets name them a, b, c
I have create 3 process to run those functions separately.
I have separate logging in those functions, which works just fine and logs in 3 different log files.

Now, I want them all to log on console as well as write in the file.

I start logging as:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                            format='%(asctime)s %(name)s.%(funcName)s +%(lineno)s: %(levelname)-8s [%(process)d] %(message)s',
                            filename=logfile,
                            filemode='a')
```

What all I tried:
Creating a stream handler and adding it to the root, but it didn't work for me.

Any help is appreciated.
I am happy to answer any doubts and forgive me if I missed out on any detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Adding the above mentioned line in all the 3 functions resolved my issue.